# Reference: Does this type of non-abelian group, where it can be broken down via a direct product, have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, terminology, definition

A non-abelian group $G$ has property $X$ if there exist non-trivial groups $A$, $B$ such that $A$ is abelian, $B$ is non-abelian, with

$$G \cong A \times B.$$

In essence, property $X$ is saying that the non-abelian group can be "broken down" into a simpler part that governs the non-abelianness, and another part that is abelian. For example, $S_3$ does not have property $X$, whereas $S_3 \times C_2$ clearly does.

Is there a name for the types of non-abelian groups with property $X$? Or without it?

Comment: Why are you interested in this property? With no restrictions on abelianness this is called being "decomposable." And I think your examples are reversed.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan my bad, fixed the error. I'm just playing around with stuff, but mainly interested in it since if a non-abelian group can be broken down this way, we can consider the smallest such $B$ as the subgroup that essentially describes the structure of the non-abelianness of the group.

Comment: It's probably more standard to measure the non-abelianness of a group $G$ by quotients like $G/Z(G)$ or $G/[G,G]$. Not that there's anything wrong with playing around with other ideas :) but if you don't know about the center and commutator subgroup of a group, this is a good excuse to learn about them.

Comment: @Robin: it's not clear what you mean by "essentially describes the structure of the non-abelianness." Consider, for example, the Heisenberg group $H_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p) over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. This group is nonabelian and indecomposable but it is also, in some sense, very close to being abelian: in fact it is a central extension of an abelian group $C_p^2$ by another abelian group $C_p$, and this central extension is in a precise sense the "only source of non-abelianness" in this group.

Comment: It also has the property that its center is $C_p$ while its abelianization is $C_p^2$ which ties back up with Greg's comment. If a group has the form $A \times G$ where $A$ is abelian then $A$ will appear in both the center and the abelianization but this is not very common and groups can have quite large centers or abelianizations (as above) while still being indecomposable (which most groups which arise "in practice" are).

Comment: To summarize the comments, being a direct product is a *very* special situation which you will rarely encounter in the wild wild west of small groups. Extensions, semidirect products, wreath products, Zappa-Szep products etc. of smaller, sometimes also abelian groups, appear more often. And no, there is probably no name for your property.